# Selenium webdriver using switch_to_windows() and printing the title doesn't print the title.

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code

```
for handle in browser.window_handles:
    print "Handle = ",handle
    browser.switch_to_window(handle);
    elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("title")
    print elem.get_attribute("value")
```

I am getting the following output

```
Handle =  {564f8459-dd20-45b8-84bf-97c69f369738}
None
Handle =  {85338322-5e58-4445-8fe3-3e822d5a0caf}
None
```

After getting the handle I switch to the window and print the title. Why am I not seeing any title. Won't there be any titles? When I see the html source for the page I see the title tag though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title of the page wouldn't be in a `value` attribute of a `title` element, it would be the text contents of that element.

The correct way to access that text would be `browser.find_element_by_tag_name("title").text`

Or even easier, just access `browser.title`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the contents? I basically want to check whether it is 404 Not found error or not.

Comment: Great now I am able to get the title. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 43):

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
title=driver.title
```

You can do it simply use the code above.
driver.window_handles[-1] would get the lastest window.

Comment: You are a genius Moxi!!

Comment: "minus one" is always the most recent opened window?

Comment: @JuanÁlvarezArquillos, no it's not. My browser opens the new tab immediately after the tab from which it was opened.